# Firebase Cloud Functions: How to push data using wildcards in http requests

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm exploring new Cloud Functions feature in Firebase, so I know how wildcards work in Realtime database triggers, but when I'm trying to add wildcards in http request, it ignores wildcards and pushes new data into the new **{userId}** object.

Basically, I'm trying to make a function, which will take data from all the users in 'today' object and push it into 'yesterday' object (something like statistics or process). For that I'm using [this topic](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/delete-unused-accounts-cron) based on cron example.

I have started with building simple function triggered by http request, with an idea of pushing some data for all the users (**{userId}** wildcard), but the data is being pushed into new **{userId}** object, ignoring the wildcard.

```
exports.addEntry = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const value = req.query.addValue;
  admin.database().ref('users/{userId}').push({value}).then(snapshot => {
  res.redirect(303, snapshot.ref); });
});
```

Question: how to make this function push the data to all users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for wiring up a wild-card in a trigger, does not apply for building a path to a database reference. There you'll have to use regular string interpolation:

```
exports.addEntry = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const value = req.query.addValue;
  admin.database().ref('users/'+userId).push({value}).then(snapshot => {
  res.redirect(303, snapshot.ref); });
});
```

Or ES6 template literals:

```
exports.addEntry = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const value = req.query.addValue;
  admin.database().ref(`users/${userId}`).push({value}).then(snapshot => {
  res.redirect(303, snapshot.ref); });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to push data to all useIds, and not only the given one?

Comment: Sure. To do that, loop over the users and push the same value to each.