# How to access uid for each user in Firebase database HTTP triggers

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I know how wildcard work with firebase database triggers. However with Firebase triggers, I am experiencing some difficulty.

My aim is to have a cloud function that writes to my database `/users` node for each user. I followed the example given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42739160/firebase-cloud-functions-how-to-push-data-using-wildcards-in-http-requests) but it returns the error code :

```
`userID` not defined.
```

Below is the JSON of my users node :

```
users:{
  "1YrpX2W2xnMPoy4YGpZcOE0xJ5g2" : {
    "email" : "muyiwaawoniyi@hotmail.com",
    "fullname" : "Muyiz",
    "selection" : [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ],
    "teamname" : "Donawon",
    "total" : 12,
    "userName" : "muyiwaawoniyi@hotmail.com",
    "week1" : 0,
    "week10" : 0,
    "week11" : 0,
    "week12" : 0,
    "week2" : 0,
    "week3" : 0,
    "week4" : 0,
    "week5" : 0,
    "week6" : 12,
    "week7" : 0,
    "week8" : 0,
    "week9" : 0
  },
  "6K9rQiZQ3jaV38WWtDbNwxhqIwc2" : {
    "email" : "dami.etomi@gmail.com",
    "fullname" : "Dami Etomi",
    "selection" : 0,
    "teamname" : "Bayern Neverlosin'",
    "total" : 0,
    "userName" : "dami.etomi@gmail.com",
    "week1" : 0,
    "week10" : 0,
    "week11" : 0,
    "week12" : 0,
    "week2" : 0,
    "week3" : 0,
    "week4" : 0,
    "week5" : 0,
    "week6" : 0,
    "week7" : 0,
    "week8" : 0,
    "week9" : 0
  }
}
```

Below is my cloud function:

```
 exports.sync = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

   admin.database().ref('users/'+ userId + '/week1').set(10); 
   res.send('it worked');

 });
```

Is there a way that the function can `set` 10 t the `week1` node of each user? I understand that this involves looping through the users node but I cant seem to get how to make a database reference without entering `{userID}` as a wildcard.

Could the back quotation marks ```` be used to access the `selection` array under each user? I assume just writing `userSnapshot.val().selection` wouldnt iterate through the users to get each selection array for each users so maybe

```
`${userSnapshot.val()}`.selection; would do the trick?
```

The final code would then look as such:

```
exports.sync = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
   admin.database().ref('users').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
       var updates = {};
       snapshot.forEach(function(userSnapshot) {
           var selection = `${userSnapshot.val()}`.selection;
           updates[`/users/${userSnapshot.key}/week1`] = 10;
       });
       admin.database().ref().update(updates).then(function() {
           res.send('it worked');
       });
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update each user, you'll need to attach a listener to `/users`, loop over the results, and update each of them. In code:

```
exports.sync = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
   admin.database().ref('users').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
       var updates = {};
       snapshot.forEach(function(userSnapshot) {
           updates[`/users/${userSnapshot.key}/week1`] = 10;
       });
       admin.database().ref().update(updates).then(function() {
           res.send('it worked');
       });
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. ! it worked. I notice the use of the ` ` backquotes. Is that something that is to be used for nodes that vary with each user. So for example, can it be used to say access the "selection" node under each user? I will edit the question to reflect my question.

Comment: The backquotes are ES6 trick: template literals. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals